# A command/environment for "spot the error" type of multiple choice tests

Tags: environments

I wonder if there is already a package that makes me create a *spot the error* kind of test like the one below:

[image]

This must preferably be in an enumerate environment.

I tried a `tikz` approach but I could not make it work out.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usetkzobj{all}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The principal \tikz [remember picture] \node (said) {}; that \tikz [remember picture] \node (weather) {}; the government \tikz [remember picture] \node (announces) {}; a holiday or not, his school \tikz [remember picture] \node (hold) {}; classes. \tikz [remember picture] \node (error) {};
\end{enumerate}

    
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\def\abovebelow#1#2#3{
\node at (#1) {\underline{#2}};
\node [below=1pt of #1] {#3};
}

\abovebelow{said}{said}{A}
\abovebelow{weather}{weather}{B}
\abovebelow{announces}{announces}{C}
\abovebelow{hold}{will still hold}{D}
\abovebelow{error}{NO ERRROR}{E}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Below is the output.

[image]

I am looking for a general solution, something that can be used in list environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I don't think you need a drawing package here, I just used `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\newcounter{qn}
\renewcommand\theqn{\Alph{qn}}
\newcommand\qn[1]{%
{\refstepcounter{qn}\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\\
\noalign{\vskip-.2ex}\hline\noalign{\vskip.2ex}\multicolumn{1}{c}{\theqn}\end{tabular}}}

\newcommand\qnx{{%
\par\qn{NO ERROR}\setcounter{qn}{0}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The principal \qn{said} that \qn{weather} the government \qn{announces} a holiday or not, his school \qn{will still hold} classes. \qnx
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. What does `\restepcounter` do? I think it is more beautiful to change from left alignment to centered. The pictures I posted might suggest that the `no error` choice is on separate paragraph but that's easily settled by removing `\par` in the definition.

Comment: `\refstepcounter` is just "counter=counter+1", with some additional stuff that makes it work correctly in sectioning counters (i.e. to make "subsection=0" whenever "section=section+1"). Here, `\stepcounter` could be used to, which does not do this additional stuff.

Comment: you could use `\stepcounter` but if you use \refstepcounter you can go `\qn{\label{zzz}weather}` ... `you might want to look closely at \ref{zzz}`  Basically whenever you auto-number something it's a good idea to use refstepcounter as you always wish later you could refer to it That's why I used refstepcounter before the table in its own group rather thanjust before the counter is printed so it is in scope for a `\label` in the argument